# @Url.action with Parameter name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am using following code to generate image with link to controller action:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ViewProduct", "ShopWindow", new {id=prod._id,title = prod.ProductTitle})">
 <img class="group list-group-image" src="@Url.Content(prod.ImagePath)?w=150&h=150" alt="" />
   </a>
```

The above code generates the links like :

> http://localhost:53298/ShopWindow/ViewProduct/58cbd66ad2b0c91b00b1eb94/CK1Red

is there a way to create link with parameters name like:

> http://localhost:53298/ShopWindow/ViewProduct?id=58cbd66ad2b0c91b00b1eb94&title=CK1Red

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have MVC Route `/{controller}/{action}/id/title` defined in your `RouteConfig`  then it automatically appends  `id, title` as querystring parameters to the generated URL.